# Jquery Autocomplete looping

Tags: jquery, loops, autocomplete, dynamically-generated

I want to attach autocomplete to dynamically generated input boxes.
I am able to do this with those who are generated from outside events(such as the click of a button).
BUT
in the required case, the input boxes are being generated on the ONSELECT event of a previous input box which has autocomplete attached to it.

In other words, initially I have an input box(with autocomeplete) on my page. When an option is selected(ONSELECT) into it, it generates another input box. PROBLEM-The generated input box should also have autocomplete attached to it, whose ONSELECT event should generate another input box, and this should go on forever.

I mainly need the logic behind this. I am ok with syntax. Just don't know how to approach the problem of looping.

I have read the other questions here which need the same thing done, but in their case, the elements are being generated externally. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT- I am new here don't know how to post the code formatted-
@ Rob --- Thanks. I liked your idea. But I didn't get why you have used .val('') in the end. Well, it's still not working. I tried other similar ways too(like appending the clones to the parent element (div#in)). the alerts are showing up on select. So that means the onselect event is being fired. Here's the code   --

```
$.post("returncategory.php",
       {},
            function(data)
            {
                $('.cat').autocomplete({
                    source: data,
                    type:'json', 
                    minchar: 1, 
                    fillin: false,
                    onSelect: function() {
                        //alert($(this).parent().get());
                        //$(this).clone(true, true).appendTo($(this).parent());
                        //$(this).clone(true, true).appendTo('#in');
                        $(this).clone(true, true).insertAfter($(this)).val();
                    }
                });


            },
            "JSON");
```

Edit: corrected code formatting

EDIT: I found the solution  :) Thanks a lot for your input Rob !!
Here's what i did -

```
$('.cat').live('click', function() {

                $(this).autocomplete({
                url: "returncategory.php",
                type: "json",
                minchar: 1,
                onSuggest: function() {

                },
                onSelect: function() {
                   $('#clicker').click();
                }
            });
            $(this).focus();
     });

$('#clicker').bind('click', function() {
   var newItem = $("<br><br><input class='cat' type='text'name='td_products["+1+"]'/>");
   $('#in').append(newItem);
   newItem.find('input').autocomplete({
                url: "returncategory.php",
                type: "json",
                minchar: 1,
                onSuggest: function() {

                },
                onSelect: function() {
                   $('#clicker').click();
                }
            });
```

});

P.S. I am very happy. And now I also know how to post formatted code here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say on select, you should grab the jQuery reference to the current input, then do `$this.clone(true, true).insertAfter($this).val('')`

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Try debugging $(this). Make sure it's referring to the #cat input and not something else.  Try `onSelect: function() { $(this).remove() }` and see if the input goes away. I'm not sure exactly which autocomplete plugin you're using, but I would recommend using the jQuery UI one, it's very good

Comment: Okay, autocomplete uses "this.ac" as the reference, so the following code started working . the box that was generated was performing autoomplete. but when a selection was made from the second box, the third box was generated but it didn't support autocomplete. Here's the code -----$('.cat').autocomplete({
                url: "returncategory.php",
                type: "json",
                minchar: 1,
                onSelect: function() {
                        $(this.ac).clone(true, true).insertAfter(this.ac);
                }
            });